# Program data folders in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, directory, organization, application-data

This is a more general and noob question. I am developing a small application in Linux (Ubuntu, to be more precise) and at this point I have an **executable**, a **shared library** (.so), a **configuration** file (.conf) with some settings to be read by the application at the beginning, a **data folder** with images and other resources to be used during the application life-time (resources that can be also modified, deleted) and of course, I would need some file for **logs** and messages (right now I am using `syslog`).

So, my question is, where should each one of these be stored when the application is installed on a client's computer? What is the standard way of organizing all the application's files in Linux? On Windows everything would be found usually in the C:\Program Files\(App Folder) but it looks like on Linux things are more (or less) organized. Can you give me some advices on this matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Program data were historically stored in dot-prefixed folders in user's home directory. Modern Linux distributions tends to use ~/.config/program_name folder.

For all files that will not be modified after distibution follow [Linux standard](https://wiki.debian.org/FilesystemHierarchyStandard):

Comment: So, that is where application specific data is stored (including big resource files, like those used by games ).

Comment: I think so. (not exactly sure about very big files). Only modifiable data should go there obviously (for example images distributed with the program go to /usr/share)

Comment: ~/.config/program_name is for user specific data, common data goes to /usr/share, binaries to /usr/bin, shared libraries to /usr/lib etc. Logs normally go under /var/log, but probably it's enough to log to syslog, which is system log.

Answer (score 0):

Ex: project dir: ABC 
sub directories:

logs - keep log files 
conf - keep configuration files here
bin - executable binaries here
traps - any trap mesg

then depend on what application we develop

Along with you can set level for starting your application from boot level if required.